# how to get all local areas of only a particular city

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have a text box to enter local areas of city (which is in back end), only particular areas of the defined city should come in google api autocomplete.

I have tried code, but it is showing other cities local areas also

here is the code i have tried:

```
function initialize() {

var latcity = $("#latcity ").val();
var longcity = $("#longcity").val();
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
new google.maps.LatLng(latcity ,longcity ),
new google.maps.LatLng(latcity ,longcity ));
var input = document.getElementById('enteredaddress');
var options = {
  bounds: defaultBounds,
  types: ['establishment']
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
    var address = $("#pick-addrs").val();
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
        return;
    }
});
```

}

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<input type='text' name='localaddress' id="localaddress">
<input type='hidden' name='latcity' id="latcity" value="LATVALUE">
<input type='hidden' name='longcity' id="longcity" value="LONGVALUE">
```

Im using latitude and longitude of a city

Comment: have you found the solution?